# what is "consistency Groups" on failure transactions of hyperledger frabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I had developed an chaincode for hyperledger fabric, and now (with new version that I have deployment on an environment, it launchs me this message:

> Transaction failure. Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The proposal responses have 2 inconsistent groups with 0 that are invalid. Expected all to be consistent and none to be invalid..

Could you describe me what is inconsistent groups that the error shows? I'm searching information but I don't find details about it, so I can't understand what happen with my transaction on the new version.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are having an endorsement policy which requires endorsement from two peers. However endorsement results for same transaction proposal turns out to be different. Which basically means your chaincode have non-deterministic code, meaning calling same chaincode with same parameters results with different responses. This is why you have 2 inconsistent groups.

Comment: Ok, I understand you and very thank for your fast answer. With your answer, I have been able to fix it doing the transaction with a peer instead two temporally, while I do tests. I'm thinking that it can be caused by a date.

Comment: this is most likely the case :)